# jQuery Mask Plugin with r shiny textInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, textinput, jquery-mask

Is there a way to do something like [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) with a `R-Shiny textInput`?

I'm trying to make a `textInput` display a mask as I'm typing.

Exemple: I want to type 11111111111 and, as I type, the textInput value displays 111.111.111-11.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? 
Or something more fancy? ;)

```
library(shiny)
library(stringi)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("textin", "Enter Text"),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    textout <- input$textin
    textout <- paste(stri_sub(textout, 1, 3),".",
                     stri_sub(textout, 4, 6), ".",
                     stri_sub(textout, 7, 9), "-",
                     stri_sub(textout, 10, 12), ".",
                     stri_sub(textout, 13, 14), ".")

    print(textout)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm really thinking of something more fancy. I would like to be able to type in the textInput (or something similar) in a way that the textInput displays a mask as I'm typing not in a regular textOutput, but in the same space that I'm typing. I dont know if its possible.

The effect I would like to reproduce in Shiny can be observed in jQuery Mask Plugin (https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).